# Vibrating membrane tension per unit length

Tags: classical-mechanics, vibrations

I have been working on the problem of a vibrating membrane, with all the assumptions to make it ideal, but I still can't figure out why the tension per unit length multiply like that:
[image: Vibrating membrane]
if $T$ is the tension per unit length, why in the image on the right it is not multiplied by the length $\Delta x$, but by $\Delta y$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think back to the 1D example of tension in a string, and look at the tensions at the ends of a small slice of length $\Delta x$. This is essentially the right-hand figure in your question, replacing  $T\Delta y$ with the usual tension $T$.

Now, imagine stretching that string out along the $y$-axis a small distance $\Delta y$ to get an equivalent of your small membrane element. There is now a tension per unit length, and the total force is acting along this new length $\Delta y$. This means the tension force along the $x$-direction is given by $T\Delta y$. A similar argument holds for the tension force in the $y$-direction.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Lets look at the equations for  $~u(x,y)=u(x)$

Newton second low in transversal direction

$$dm\,\frac{dv}{dt}=F\sin(\beta)-F\sin(\alpha)\tag 1$$

with $\quad(~\alpha\ll~\beta\ll)$
$$dm=\mu\,ds\\
\tan(\alpha)=\frac{du}{dx}\quad,\alpha=\frac{du}{dx}\\
ds^2=dx^2+du^2\quad\Rightarrow\quad ds=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^2}\,dx\approx dx\\
v=\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{d x}{dt}
$$
and
$$\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\approx\alpha+d\alpha-\alpha=d\alpha=\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\,dx$$

thus equation (1)

$$\mu\,dx\,\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=F\,\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}\,dx$$

thus it should be $~T\,dx~$

Comment: Sorry, I think you concluded wrong. The force should be $T\Delta y$ not $T\Delta x$